# Foreach print table doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, html-table, procedural

```
echo "<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">";
foreach($array as $key => $value){
echo "";
echo "<tr><td><a href=\"".$url1.$key."\"><ax>" . $value . "</ax></a></td><td>".$url1.$key."</td></tr>";
echo "<br>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Why doesn't this display the table?

Comment: What is the value of `$array`?

Comment: What do you think `<ax>` does?

Comment: It works. A CSS-Setting blocked the table.

Answer (score 0):

is that in HTML5?

`cellpadding`and `cellspacing`are not supported in HTML5

Comment: the `<br>`tags are definitely redundant, also the empty echo before each `<tr>` is unnecessary/redundant. What happens if you delete those two lines? And what is the `<ax>`tag?

Comment: ax tag is color:white;.. now it looks like that, but still not working: `echo "<table border=\"1\">";
foreach($array as $key => $value){
echo "<tr><td><a href=\"".$url1.$key."\">" . $value . "</a></td><td>".$url1.$key."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";`

Comment: hmmm... Personally, I would replace the escaped double-quotes with (unescaped) single quotes, but that can't be the reason, I suppose. Check the contents of your $array and of the $url1 variable, otherwise I can't think of anything else

Comment: the output is correct but it does not display the table. i don't know why.

Comment: You mean it displays the data, just not the table? Is there any CSS?

Comment: Yes it displays the data but not the table. Yes there is CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2",
        "key3" => "value3",
    );

    echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">';
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        echo('<tr><td>'.$key.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>');
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Works fine with a correctly constructed array.